# Missing tools from my property panel

Tags: interface, lighting, navigation

I am following a tutorial for rendering with Blender, and some of the tools that he is using in the video don't appear for me. I have the navigation menu up fine, and most of the tools are there, but for example the lightbulb is missing and I don't know how to add it on.
Attached is the photo of his navigation bar compared to mine. Any advice?

[image: Navigation bar with 12 icons]

[image: Navigation bar with 14 icons, but different icons to the first image]

Comment: It seems a light object is selected in the video. This property panel is contextual (the content will depend on the selected object)

Comment: Those are not "tools" they are properties tabs, and they depend on the currently active object. If you don't see what you expect it is because you have the wrong object type selected.

Comment: The only thing that's a bit strange is that in your screenshot where you obviously have a mesh object selected, the _Collection_ tab is missing. Could it be that you are using a much older version than used in the tutorial? At least I don't know a setting where you can disable the collections...